# Show a text box depending on two columns of a spreadsheet in Google UI app

Tags: user-interface, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps, var

We're trying to show a text box depending if somebodies row has "Y" in it. In column B we have a load of email addresses, Column C has emails, column D is empty and Column E defines manager or not ("Y").

What we're trying to do is show the text box if the signed in user has a Y in the adjoining column. However, everything we've tried seems to either always show the text box or never show the text box.

I'm only going to show the code for this particular function as there is approx 4000 lines over the who script.

This is the way we've got it so far. We think we're quite close (although we may not be!).

```
 function vUser(app){

    var userID = Session.getActiveUser();


   var sheet  = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREADSHEET_ID2).getSheetByName("Managers");

   var values = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),13).getValues(); 


  for (var i in values){  
 if ((values[i][0] == userID) && (values[i][2] == 'Y')){

   var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
   createForm_(app);
   app.getElementById('manager').setVisible(true);
   app.getElementById('managerTextBox').setVisible(true);
 return app;


 }else {

  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  createForm_(app);

   continue;  // entered this to try and make it read down. Now shows 30 of the generic questions as my username is on the 30th row. Does show the 'manager' and 'managertextbox' once, however.
  return app; //removed when continue; is included. 
 }  

 }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

how about something like:

```
for (var i in values){  
if ((values[i][0] == userID) && (values[i][2] == 'Y')){

    var is_manager = 1;
}}


if (is_manager ==1){
    var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
    createForm_(app);
    app.getElementById('manager').setVisible(true);
    app.getElementById('managerTextBox').setVisible(true);
  return app;
}
```

Comment: We figured it out in the end. It was to do with the 'createForm_(app)' which was being created in another file and linked, so in effect, all the code I provided was completely useless